# For loop within if statement in Java

Tags: java

I've got a segment of code in which I'm having to repeat an action a number of times so a basic if statement won't suffice. My solution was to use For loops within the if statement. I just wondered if there's a more efficient way of going about this. I know it's 101 stuff but I'm fairly new to Java. Thanks in advance.

Code example below:

```
int a = 20
int b = a - anObject.getValue()

if (anObject.getValue() == a)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < a; x++) 
         { 
            //do stuff that needs repeating
         }
}
else 
{
    for (int y = 0; y < b; y++)
         {
            //do other stuff that needs repeating
         }
}
```

Comment: It depends on what stuff needs repeating, **what** stuff needs repeating?

Comment: Looks like a candidate for a specific method to come into play: `int val = anObject.getValue(); if (val == a) { myMethod(a); } else { myMethod(b); }`

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 20;
int b = a - anObject.getValue();

int limit = anObject.getValue()==a ? a : b;
for (int i=0; i<limit; ++i) { 
    //do stuff that needs repeating
}
```

You don't need to call `getValue` twice.

```
int b = a - anObject.getValue();
int limit = b==0 ? a : b;
```

If the 'stuff' is different, i.e. you're trying to extract the algorithm.

```
int a = 20;
int b = a - anObject.getValue();
final int limit;
final IntConsumer consumer;
if (b == 0) {
    limit = a;
    consumer = i -> {
        // do stuff
    };
} else {
    limit = b;
    consumer = i -> {
        // do other stuff
    };
}

IntStream.range(0, limit).forEach(consumer);
```

(Notice the weird syntax.};

You could use a `for` loop instead of the `IntStream` statement(it'll be faster).

```
for (int i=0; i<limit; ++i) { 
    consumer.accept(i);
}
```

Or the good old "dumb" way of doing it, repeating the condition:

```
int a = 20;
int b = a - anObject.getValue();
int limit = b==0 ? a : b;
for (int i=0; i<limit; ++i) {
    if (b == 0) {
        // do stuff
    } else {
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: @user85421 I was making that assumption. Already expanded my answer.

Comment: @user85421 Oh yeah, thanks. Too preoccupied geting the `IntStream` nonsense right.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions so far. I should have clarified, apologies. By other stuff, I meant "DIFFERENT' stuff.

Comment: @yoshmv35 It's what was meant by "repeat" that confused me - I went off thinking that was duplicated and you were apply a slightly differently parameterised version of an algorithm to the same code.

Comment: Hawtin. Sorry yeah I just meant iterations of "do stuff" or "do other stuff". Thanks for your help!